# For which functions is there an efficient estimator?

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ sample from $Exp(\theta)$. For which functions $\tau$ is there an efficient estimator of the parameter $\tau(\theta)$.

I think I should use Cramér-Rao bound, but how should I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Did you already try the Cramer-Rao bound? If so, what happened when you did and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @William I can not understand for what functions there is such an estimate

Comment: Well based on the little I know, in order to use Cramer-Rao, it seems that one needs the estimator to be unbiased. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound And in order to make sure that the term "efficient estimator" is well-defined, one needs to have specified a choice of loss function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient_estimator Are you perhaps having difficulty choosing a loss function? Or determining whether $\tau(\theta)$ is an unbiased estimator? Clarifying further will help those who know how to help you (I am unfortunately not one of them) to help you.

Comment: Also if no one helps you here after a week on Math.SE, consider posting the question on stats.stackexchange.com  -- make sure to wait at least week though, otherwise both questions on both sites are likely to be deleted.